# Components of $\mathbb{S}^2$ as a closed combinatorial surface.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces, simplicial-complex

I'm trying to solve the following problem, and I'm not having much luck:

> Suppose that the sphere $ \mathbb{S}^2 $
>   is given the structure of a closed combinatorial surface.
>   Let $C$ be a subcomplex that is a simplicial circle. Suppose that $ \mathbb{S}^2\backslash C$
>   has two components. Indeed,
>   suppose that this is true for every simplicial circle in $ \mathbb{S}^2
> $
>   . Let $E$ be one of these components.
>
> Let $\sigma _1$ be a 1-simplex in $C$ . Since $\mathbb{S}^2$
>   is a closed combinatorial surface, $\sigma _1$ is adjacent to two
>   2-simplices. Show that precisely one of these 2-simplices lies in $\overline{E}$.

I've managed to show that each of the two 2-simplices adjacent to $\sigma _1$ must be in one of the two components, but I can't work out how to show that they must be in different components (i.e. that if one is in $E$ then the other must be in the other component).

I saw the answer to this question [An exercise on components of $\mathbb{S}^2$ as a closed combinatorial surface.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221495/an-exercise-on-components-of-mathbbs2-as-a-closed-combinatorial-surface), but the relevant part of the answer seems much more advanced than any of the material I've been learning (I haven't encountered barycenters or null-homologous loops, for instance).

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to observe is the following:

> Lemma 1: For every 2-simplex $\tau$ in $\mathbb S^2$ there exists a 2-simplex $\tau'$ which shares an edge with $C$ and such that $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are in the same component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$.

Let me assume that you believe that.  As an immediate consequence,

> Corollary 2: For each of the two components of $\mathbb S^2 - C$ there exists a 2-simplex in that component that shares an edge with $C$.

Okay, now for the real work. starting from $\sigma_1$, let's list the 1-simplices along $C$ in order as $C = \sigma_1 \cup \sigma_2 \cup\cdots\cup \sigma_K$. Let $v_k = \sigma_{k} \cap \sigma_{k+1}$ (for all $k=1,...,K$, using addition modulo $K$).

The two 2-simplices on opposite sides of $\sigma_1$ can be written $\tau_{1L}$, $\tau_{1R}$ (if you imagine yourself standing on $\sigma_1$ looking towards $\sigma_2$, $\tau_L$ is on your left and $\tau_R$ is on your right).

Now move forward from $\sigma_1$ past $v_1$ to $\sigma_2$, and you'll see that the 2-simplices on opposite sides of $\sigma_2$ can be written as $\tau_{2L}$, $\tau_{2R}$ so that $\tau_{1L}$ and $\tau_{2L}$ are in the same component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$, and so that $\tau_{1R}$ and $\tau_{2R}$ are in the same component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$.

Continue in this fashion by induction. For each $k=1,...,K$ you will then have listed the 2-simplices that share an edge with $C$ as $\tau_{1L},...,\tau_{KL}$ and $\tau_{1R},...,\tau_{KR}$ so that $\tau_{1L},\tau_{2L},...,\tau_{KL}$ are all in the same component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$, and so that $\tau_{1R},\tau_{2R},...,\tau_{KR}$ are all in the same component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$.

If $\tau_{1L}$ and $\tau_{1R}$ were in the same component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$ then it would follow that all 2-simplices sharing an edge with $C$ are in a single component of $\mathbb S^2 - C$, contradicting Corollary 2.

Therefore, $\tau_{1L}$ and $\tau_{1R}$ are in opposite components of $\mathbb S^2 - C$.

Comment: Thanks, that's so helpful! I have one question though - I certainly believe lemma 1 (it seems intuitively pretty clear), but how would you go about proving that?

Comment: Very briefly, it's a consequence of the topological property of "connectivity", which the sphere $\mathbb S^2$ possesses. In just a bit more detail, connectivity implies that for any pair of 2-simplices $\tau,\tau'$, there is a sequence $\tau=\tau_0,\tau_1,...,\tau_L$ such that for each $l=1,...,L$ the pair of 2-simplices $\tau_{l-1}$, $\tau_l$ shares an edge.